# Можно ли в delphi сделать маршрутизатор?

Tags: delphi

Можно ли в delphi сделать маршрутизатор для переброски ip адресов и портов, если можно на примере?  Ну, например, обращение идет на ip и порт компa 1, где он переадресовывается на ip и порт компа 2.

Comment: Сделать можно все.
Что именно Вы называете маршрузатором не понятно.

Опишите более конкретно что вы хотите.

Comment: Прокси, что ли?)

Comment: есть такая штука: тезис Тьюринга-Черча. Неформально из него вытекает например следующее: 1) на машине Тьюринга можно решить любую вычислимую задачу. 2) если на языке программирования можно реализовать машину Тьюринга, то на нем можно решить любую вычислимую задачу

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по словосочетанию "Indy Proxy Delphi" помогут Вам решить этот вопрос, так как все равно вопрос задан размыто.

Comment: Вообще у него что-то ближе к днс-рулетке по описанию, не клиент-*через прокси*-сервер, а клиент-сервер-*другой сервер*. Но в принципе в некотором смысле это тоже прокси) Плюсик.

Алсо поделюсь, довелось попользоваться <a href="http://www.realthinclient.com/order.htm">real thin client</a>'ом - шикарная штука, все что надо и намного больше.

Answer (score 0):

копайте в сторону IdMappedPort

Да что там копать-то?

принимает на один порт, транслирует на определенный ай-пи, на другой порт...

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую покопать в сторону winpcap, для начала можете глянуть ссылку, там есть примеры на Си
https://ntu-kpi.comp.programming.narkive.com/m8kvlova/winpcap